# How to get coordinates of an highlighted text in Eggplant

Tags: eggplant

I have a text box, the size will change, using Ctrl+a I have highlight the text in the text box, how to get the coordinates of this highlighted text? so that I can readtext() that area. Actually I tried copying the highlighted text to clip board and then to put in a variable. But if I compare with an existing text I am getting an \n for the end of the line,  if I compare the text retrieved with original text , they don't match. so I am thinking of using readtext()

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with format function. Should get rid of escape sequences.

```
typeText controlKey&a
typeText controlKey&c
put remoteClipboard() into yourVariable
put format("%b", yourVariable) into newVariable
```

**Reference link:** [SenseTalk](http://docs.testplant.com/ePF/SenseTalk/stk-text-data-manipulation.htm)

Answer (score 0):

how are you comparing in your scenario?

When your use "contains" in your condition you can achieve what you have expected.